# Triggering a move on an UITableView?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have the following code in my DataSource class

```
public override bool CanMoveRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
   return true;
}

public override void MoveRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath sourceIndexPath, NSIndexPath destinationIndexPath)
{
       ... code for swapping the location of stuff in a list
    }
```

How do I trigger a 'move'? If I swipe my UITableView I get my delete button, but how do I get a 'move'? Do I need to put a button and then put the table into a BeginEditting mode first? Any sample code for doing that?

Comment: The [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1) section in the Table View Programming Guide explains this in detail.  Although the sample code there is in Objective-C, it shouldn't be hard to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the table to allow you to perform the move action, you need to set the table into "editing" mode ( `tableView.Editing = true;` ).